# onSuccess callback in Plaid Link not updating

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, plaid, usecallback

I've built a `PlaidLink` component using `react-plaid-link` as below. There's no issues when building with the standard way - passing in only `public_token` and `account_id` to the request body.

However, when I attempt to pass in `stripeUid` to the request body, only an empty string (the initial value of the `stripeUid` state) is passed. This is despite the value of `stripeUid` being updated and passed in correctly from the parent via `props`. For some reason `stripeUid` does not update within the `useCallback` hook even though the value is in the dependency array.

Any idea why the value is not updating?

```
function PlaidLink(props) {
  const [token, setToken] = useState("");
  const { achPayments, stripeUid } = props;

  async function createLinkToken() {
    const fetchConfig = {
      method: "POST",
    };
    const response = await fetch(
      API_URL + "/plaid/create-link-token",
      fetchConfig
    );
    const jsonResponse = await response.json();
    const { link_token } = jsonResponse;
    setToken(link_token);
  }

  const onSuccess = useCallback(
    (publicToken, metadata) => {
      const { account_id } = metadata;

      // Exchange a public token for an access one.
      async function exchangeTokens() {
        const fetchConfig = {
          method: "POST",
          headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            public_token: publicToken,
            account_id,
            stripeUid,
          }),
        };
        const response = await fetch(
          API_URL + "/plaid/exchange-tokens",
          fetchConfig
        );
        const jsonResponse = await response.json();
        console.log("Exchange token response:", jsonResponse);
      }

      exchangeTokens();
    }, [stripeUid]
  );

  const { open, ready } = usePlaidLink({
    token,
    onSuccess,
  });

  // get link_token from your server when component mounts
  useEffect(() => {
    createLinkToken();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (achPayments && ready) {
      open();
    }
  }, [achPayments, ready, open]);

  return <div></div>;
}

export default PlaidLink;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with Stripe API but from reading a code I see a possible issue with the code.

Following the chain of events, there is one `usePlaidLink` and two `useEffects`. When the component mounts, it `createLinkToken` in one of the effects and `open` in the other (assuming it is `ready`).

However, when `stripeUid` changes, it doesn't re-fire the effects. So, that's a hint for me.

Next, checking the source of `usePlaidLink` here: https://github.com/plaid/react-plaid-link/blob/master/src/usePlaidLink.ts gives me an idea: it doesn't do anything when `options.onSuccess` changes, only when `options.token` changes. This is their dependency array:

```
[loading, error, options.token, products]
```

So it looks like your code is correct as far as effects in react go, but it doesnt't work together because changing the `onSuccess` doesn't do anything.

How to solve:

- make a pull request into the open source library to fix the issue there
- inline that library into your code and fix it for yourself
- use "keyed components" to unmount and mount the component again when the uid changes instead of updating to work around the issue
- some other solution

Comment: Very interesting and good explanation. This makes sense now. I ended up developing a workaround in the end. Did not pass `stripeUid` in this request body. Made a subsequent api call with this info instead after `onSuccess` had completed. Split the server-side logic to suit, which kept the code more modular anyways.